# Rename files uploaded by paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, file-rename

How do I rename files uploaded by Paperclip? I have uploaded file /public/system/attachments/15/original/abc.txt

How do I rename abc.txt file into for example xyz.txt ? I know how to update file name attributes of an object, but how to make these changes on the file system?

Comment: This is not directly related. But the last commit in paperclip is one year old. That's not what I call a maintained library :) You should take a look at [carrierwave](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave)

Comment: And you can specify the uploaded filename by overriding the filename method in your uploader ...

Answer (score 1):

You need to adapt the:url and :path options from [has_attached_file](http://rubydoc.info/gems/paperclip/Paperclip/ClassMethods#has_attached_file-instance_method)

In this great [tutorial](http://thewebfellas.com/blog/2008/11/2/goodbye-attachment_fu-hello-paperclip) (thewebfellas.com) you'll find it all. :)

edit: to just move on disk, after having completed the uploading, you can use [FileUtils](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html)

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'fileutils'

FileUtils.mv('/your/old/file', '/your/new/file')
```

Oh and [File::rename](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File.html#method-c-rename) as well of course.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
File.rename("afile", "afile.bak")
```

Comment: I was looking for a way to rename a file, but your link doesn't show how to do it. There's a heading with word rename in it, but i'm not any wiser. :-(

Comment: oh, so you mean after you saved it with paperclip?

Comment: I adapted my answer already for it, you do it by moving a file. :)

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll do it that way.